# How can I plot $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 \leq x^2+y^2$?

Tags: graphing-functions, online-resources

if I use spherical coordinates $x=r\sin(a)\cos(b), y=r\sin(a)\sin(b), z=r\cos(a)$, where $a$ goes from 0 to $\pi$ and $b$ from 0 to $2\pi$ I get the following

$r^4\leq r^2\sin(a)^2$

$r^2\leq \sin^2(a)$

Do you know what shape this area has? Can I plot it with an online tool for example?

Comment: spherical coordinates go by roe, phi, and theta.

$\begin{align}
  x &= \rho\sin\phi\cos\theta\notag\\
  y &= \rho\sin\phi\sin\theta\label{spherical_cartesian}\tag{1}\\
  z &= \rho\cos\phi\notag.
\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using cylindrical coordinates. Let $x = r\cos(\theta)$, $y = r\sin(\theta)$, and keep $z$, you have that your set is

$$ \{ (r^2 + z^2)^2 \leq r^2 \} $$

For a fixed angle, the cross sectional view of the equality case can be easily graphed by, for example, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+graph+%28+%28r%5E2+%2B+z%5E2%29%5E2+%3D+r%5E2+%29).